# how to increment and decrement the value using function

Tags: java

Hi guys i am new to Java.I have created first program . but I can't get the desired output..

I want j value to 2 and then i want to increament i value till loop ends .But I am not getting the value

```
    private double i=30;
    private double j=20; 

    private double l=5;



if (l=5)
{

for (; j<=50  ; j+=2)
{
     System.out.printf("value of j is %d\n",j);
     increamenti_Value ();

}
for (; j>=4; j-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 

{
     System.out.printf("value of decrement is %d\n",j);
      increamenti_Value ();
}

}


private voide increamenti_Value ()

for (; i<=50  ; i+=2)
{
     System.out.printf("value of i is %d\n",i);


}
for (; i>=4; i-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 

{
     System.out.printf("value of decrement is %d\n",i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a minimal working example. Your code does not even compile (code outside of methods, "voide" instead of void). Anyways, I put together something working for you:

```
package test;

public class Test
{
    static private int i=30;
    static private int  j=20; 
    static private int l=5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (l==5)
        {

            for (; j<=50  ; j+=2)
            {
                System.out.printf("value of j is %d\n",j);
                increamenti_Value ();
            }
            for (; j>=4; j-=2) // i want here the value j to be 20 ... 

            {
                System.out.printf("value of decrement is %d\n",j);
                increamenti_Value ();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void increamenti_Value ()
    {
        for (; i<=50  ; i+=2) {System.out.printf("value of i is %d\n",i);}  
    }

}
```

Output is the following. Is that what you expect?

```
value of j is 20
value of i is 30
value of i is 32
value of i is 34
value of i is 36
value of i is 38
value of i is 40
value of i is 42
value of i is 44
value of i is 46
value of i is 48
value of i is 50
value of j is 22
value of j is 24
value of j is 26
value of j is 28
value of j is 30
value of j is 32
value of j is 34
value of j is 36
value of j is 38
value of j is 40
value of j is 42
value of j is 44
value of j is 46
value of j is 48
value of j is 50
value of decrement is 52
value of decrement is 50
value of decrement is 48
value of decrement is 46
value of decrement is 44
value of decrement is 42
value of decrement is 40
value of decrement is 38
value of decrement is 36
value of decrement is 34
value of decrement is 32
value of decrement is 30
value of decrement is 28
value of decrement is 26
value of decrement is 24
value of decrement is 22
value of decrement is 20
value of decrement is 18
value of decrement is 16
value of decrement is 14
value of decrement is 12
value of decrement is 10
value of decrement is 8
value of decrement is 6
value of decrement is 4
```

Comment: after j=20 , "i" started to decrement till ""50" thats fine , but i need "j" to increase 22(+2) and i started to decrement , then j=24 .. till j <=50

Answer (score 0):

use j and i as static int variable like `static int i`